# python argument 1 must have a write method

Tags: python, string, csv, export-to-csv

Hi Im trying to save a modified csv file thats been read. See code.

```
import csv

with open("Bang.csv", 'rt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    new_data = data.replace('"', '')

    for row in csv.reader(new_data.splitlines(), 
                          delimiter=' ',
                          skipinitialspace=True):
        pa = (','.join(row))
        wr = csv.writer("pa", delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow("pa")
```

I can print Data and pa but when I run I get the above mentioned error. What am I missing. Thanks

Comment: oh, you mean in the post title

Comment: `csv.writer` takes a `file` object as its first parameter

Comment: Also note that writerow() method takes a list or tupple of column values.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer), the first parameter of `csv.writer` must be a file-like object.

Suppose you want to write into the stdout (print on the screen), you can modify you code like this:

```
#pa = (','.join(row))  # you don't need to join row manually
wr = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter=',')
wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Doesnt work , seperates all the characters of pa with a ","

Comment: @MichalK Oh, my mistake, `pa` is a string object not an iterator(list). Actually, you don't need to join `row` manually, just use `wr.writerow(row)`. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know, but I think that the first argument passed to csv.writer( ) function should be a filehandler instead a string variable.